# Java JNI error for open Process with Java application

Tags: java, eclipse, jri

**I tried to open a .exe file thats filled with java .class files.. when i open it with a mouse click it works but when i open it with my Java application i get a JNI error**

The Program is called PokeMMO.exe
the website: [PokeMMo](https://pokemmo.eu/)

**im trying to get the Output stream... here is the code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("STARTING");
    System.out.println();

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] commands = {"C:\\Users\\{MY USER NAME}\\AppData\\Roaming\\PokeMMO\\PokeMMO.exe"};
    Process proc = rt.exec(commands);


    BufferedReader Input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader Error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));



    System.out.println("OUTPUT:\n");
    String s = null;
    while ((s = Input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println("ERROR OUTPUT:\n");
    while ((s = Error.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**Error log**

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

I read something about adding the libary path to the process.. **Any idea how to fix it?**

Comment: You must post the error log and/or stack trace, and tell us which statement in your code causes the error.  In general if you want to read both stdout and stderr you should use `ProcessBuilder` with its ability to combine both into one stream. Otherwise you must start separate threads so one doesn't fill up the buffer and stall your program while reading the other one.

Comment: i addet the error log

Comment: I don't see any error log in your post (and no edit history either).

Comment: now you should see it :)

Comment: btw.. im not a pro coder ... i started learn a month ago

Comment: Looks like you're missing the LWJGL library in your classpath.

Comment: Could you share the location where you have installed the client `PokeMMO`?

Answer (score 0):

Your source code works fine for me. Here `PokeMMO.exe` is missing a `Java` library.

Please use the `PATH` where you have installed `PokeMMO` i.e. (`C:\\Program Files` or `C:\\Program Files (x86)` or `C:` etc.) instead of using following `PATH`:

"C:\Users\{MY USER NAME}\AppData\Roaming\PokeMMO\PokeMMO.exe"

Comment: C:\Users\{MY USER NAME}\AppData\Roaming\PokeMMO\PokeMMO.exe **is the path where i have installed pokemmo...**

Comment: Could you please tell me what happens when you open command prompt and type the above mentioned command?

Comment: no its not.. when i use this command via command prompt it opens